# The Language is Lua and the word is "embedded"

Tags: lua, embedded

I was reading about the language "Lua" and I was confused with the three following lines :

1. Lua is designed primarily for embedded systems and clients .
2. The only competitor to Lua back then was TCL which was meant to be embedded into applications .
3. Lua is intended to be embedded into other applications,

So , what is the difference between the meaning of word "embedded" in the first line and the word "embedded" in the second and third line .
What does it mean for a language to be embedded into other applications ?

Comment: Context is everything - please include a link to where you read this.  The fist statement appear to be a confusion of the term "embedded system" (IMO)

Comment: embedded is one of those words you just ignore.  It is defined by the author when used and no reason to assume any two folks writing that word have the same definition.  Do not get caught up in definitions of words like these it interferes with your understanding and education.   If you want to learn lua learn lua (by skipping over this text you read and moving on to real text that matters).

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia

> An embedded system is a computer system with a dedicated function within a larger mechanical or electrical system, often with real-time computing constraints.

Typical examples include cars or coffee makers, where computers are embedded into the system to fulfill certain tasks.

The typical constraint is that embedded systems are often less powerful than a typical desktop computer due to cost and energy constraints. Therefore, languages to be used on embedded systems should allow for a lightweight execution. This is how "embedded" is used in the first line.

The second and third line refer to the usual application of Lua:
It is meant to be used to extend the functionality of existing programs. For example think about a coffee maker where you can specify your own coffee recipes. Then the actual control program of the coffee machine is written for example in C, while you can specify the coffee recipe in Lua. In this way, your coffee recipes that you write in Lua are embedded in the C application.

**Application of Lua in embedded systems**

Due to a comment that questions the use of Lua in embedded systems, here some examples taken from [Wikipedia's list of Lua applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_applications_using_Lua#Other_uses):

> - The Canon Hack Development Kit (CHDK), an open source firmware for Canon cameras, uses Lua as one of two scripting languages.
> - Cisco Systems uses Lua to implement Dynamic Access Policies within the Adaptive Security Appliance (ASA), and also SIP normalization in Cisco Unified Communications Manager (CUCM).
> - Custom applications for the Creative Technology Zen X-Fi2 portable media player can be created in Lua.
> - Lego Mindstorms NXT and NXT 2.0 can be scripted with Lua using third-party software.
> - LuCI, the default web interface for OpenWrt, is written primarily in Lua.
> - NodeMCU uses Lua in hardware. NodeMCU is an open source hardware platform, which can run Lua directly on the ESP8266 Wi-Fi SoC.
> - Sierra Wireless AirLink ALEOS GSM / CDMA / LTE gateways allow user applications to be written in Lua.
> - The Perimeta session border controller from Metaswitch Networks uses Lua as a scripting language to manipulate SDP data on the fly.
> - Rockbox, the open-source digital audio player firmware, supports plugins written in Lua.
> - The Squeezebox music players from Logitech support plugins written in Lua on recent models (Controller, Radio and Touch).
> - TI-Nspire calculators contain applications written in Lua, since TI added Lua scripting support with a calculator-specific API in OS 3+.

Comment: @Kaolo :Thanks a lot for great answer .
 Why would I use Lua to tell coffee recipe if everything has been coded up in C or C ++ already ?

Comment: @Kaolo : any  source code example where I can see this angle of Lua ?

Answer (score 3):

The use of the term "embedded" here is not the the same meaning as the [embedded] tag, in SO, or even the term "embedded systems" as it is conventionally used.

The link in the Wikipedia page is erroneous and misleading - the link is to "embedded systems", but the citation refers to it being an embeddable language - which is not the same thing.

Don't confuse these things - I have been developing embedded systems for many years and don't see Lua featuring *anywhere*.  It could of course be used an an embedded language in an embedded system (for end user customisation for example), but it is not an embedded systems language as such.

Comment: Definitely. This is about *embedded interpreters*, not about *embedded systems*.

Comment: @Clifford : What is an embedded interpreter ?

Answer (score 0):

1 states that Lua is for devices which have a certain purpose instead of many.

2 and 3 states that Lua may be implemented in, for instance, a C++ application to do a function.

For instance, a part of an application can use Lua, but it can also mostly use C++.

Comment: I doubt the interpretation of the fist statement - I think is is just poor use of terms - where in the world is Lua widely used in embedded systems?

Comment: @Clifford I've never seen it either so I think it never caught on or I agree with you, I guess. When I was using Lua I was only making little scripts that do certain things.

Comment: I take it back (partially).  I have seen it as a user customisation language in a router (using OpenWRT).  But I would not extend that or similar examples to say it is an embedded systems language - merely that it is a language that can be embedded in a system.  It is not a systems level language.  You cannot bring up a board from reset with it, any it requires a system runtime on which to run.

Comment: @JP :Again why to use a part in Lua when everything uses C ?

Comment: @EddieDorphy I believe it's easier to implement Lua than languages like C

Comment: @JP : But since that system is using C already doesn't it mean that C is already implemented and hence no need to deal with the difficulties of implementing it again